# chkdsk fails with "Unable to write to attribute 16 of file 0. Readable file record segment 0 is not writeable"

Tags: ntfs, chkdsk

I'm getting the subj error when running `chkdsk`, and it cannot fix the disk. This is a system disk, and when I boot from it, I get a message that a profile cannot be loaded, and I cannot even get to the logon screen.

```
C:\>chkdsk e: /f
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is SYSTEM.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
 0 percent complete. (0 of 313376 file records processed)
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 128 in file 9.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $SDS)
from file record segment 9.
313376 file records processed.
<...>
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
351893 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
3 unindexed files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
Repairing the security file record segment.
Deleting an index entry with Id 256 from index $SII of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 257 from index $SII of file 9.
<...>
Deleting an index entry with Id 269 from index $SII of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 259 from index $SDH of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 268 from index $SDH of file 9.
<...>
Deleting an index entry with Id 263 from index $SDH of file 9.
Replacing invalid security id with default security id for file 0.
Unable to write to attribute 16 of file 0.
Readable file record segment 0 is not writeable.
```

I cannot check the disk's surface with `chkdsk` 'cuz it chokes on this step. Checking it with 3rd-party tools showed no bad blocks anyway.

I've searched the Net and found similar reports, but the only way people reported to have been able to "fix" it is by reinstalling Windows or formatting the drive. None of the suggested measures helped me as well as them:

- [Install a hotfix for win2003](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/d77c0235-67aa-41d2-b704-14577924b17a/-chkdsk-windows?forum=vistaru) - not applicable, XP here, and the hotfix is for a previous SP anyway
- [Run from a recovery disk](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/chkdsk-not-completing/9f8f3e8b-0d63-4fbc-8d43-7bdb604cbfd4?db=5), [schedule `chkdsk` to run at the next boot](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/checkdisk-error-readable-file-record-segment-5-quo.1945572/), [`/i /c` options](http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=11748&hl=) - no effect
- [dismount the drive](http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=17457) - with `/x`, same error

Comment: The message that "your profile cannot be loaded" was caused by an enabled [automatic logon](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) of a regular user. Since `chkdsk` reset all the security descriptors to Full Access for `Administrators` and `SYSTEM`, the user's profile could not be loaded.  What is weird is this setting is not ignored in Safe Mode for a reason that's beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dismount" advice is correct, but it needs to be done a little bit differently.

The fact is, [`file 0` is `$Mft` and `file 9` is `$Secure`](http://ntfs.com/ntfs-system-files.htm), NTFS system files. It appears that even with `/x`, these files still stay in use -- that is what triggers the error on an attempt to overwrite their attributes.

You need to completely dismount the drive - i.e. [unassign its letter](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dm_drive_letter.mspx). And then run `chkdsk` by specifying its Volume Name that looks like this:

```
C:\>chkdsk \\?\Volume{5c11cc4f-d5f7-11e6-ab52-806e6f6e6963} /f
```

The volume name for your drive can be found in `mountvol` output:

```
C:\>mountvol
<...>
Possible values for VolumeName along with current mount points are:

    \\?\Volume{5c11cc4f-d5f7-11e6-ab52-806e6f6e6963}\
        *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

    \\?\Volume{e70bedec-8947-11df-82c0-806e6f6e6963}\
        C:\

<...>
```

Since in your case, `chkdsk` is apparently going to overwrite all or most of security descriptors, if it's a system volume, you'll then have to [restore correct permissions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313222/how-do-i-restore-security-settings-to-a-known-working-state).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with same message details
The original symptom for me was 100% disk usage and no data transfer, with incredibly long restart times forcing me to hard reset. Chkdsk failed consistently but even after unmounting/removing drive letters I continued to experience unspecified errors during chkdsk stage 3.

```
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
An unspecified error occurred (736463686b2e6378 ad7).
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e 1798)
```

Even a cold boot to Command Prompt from a Windows installation DVD wouldn't allow chkdsk to complete.

Thankfully the affected volume wasn't the boot disk, so I disconnected the SATA drive and restarted. Windows booted quickly once more, I reconnected the SATA drive and the volume reappeared in Disk Management (not sure if I should have done that but it didn't seem to hurt anything). I then ran a conventional Windows Chkdsk via the GUI and this time it had no problem fixing it, even without dismounting.

I'm not so experienced with Windows 10, but I imagine by connecting the drive after the boot I was able to pry the ownership of the drive from the grip of a Windows process.

Answer (score -1):

I would honestly run a smartdefrag on you hardrive and try chkdsk again after. I would suggest iobit's smart defrag as they really helped me with a lot of these issues.

I know you cant boot into it, try to put the hard rive in another pc as a slave and run the smart defrag against it.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: The root error `chkdsk` finds appears to be "invalid security id... for file 0." How can defragging have anything to do with it?!

Comment: I look at it this way, a defrag re-arranges your drive for optimal use. Maybe by using it, it will skip those bad sectors. or move from those bad sectors.

Comment: I already fixed the problem as written in my answer. The erroneous files were NTFS system files, a defrag program cannot do anything with them even if it wanted to (they are marked as "unmovable" during defrag).